# Splitting file dramatically increases its size

Tags: python, xml, bigdata, data-dump

I'm breaking up the 4GB Wiktionary XML data dump into smaller files, with no overlap, processing it with Python and saving distinct pages (...).

The same info, split across different files, is ballooning to 18+ GB.

Why might this be? And is there a way to avoid this?

```
import os 
import re
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['mkdir', 'WIKTIONARY_WORDS_DUMP'])

# English Wiktionary (which noneless contains many foreign words!)
f = open('enwiktionary-20151020-pages-articles.xml', 'r')

page = False
number = 1
for i, l in enumerate(f): 

    if '<page>' in l:
        word_file = open(os.path.join('WIKTIONARY_WORDS_DUMP', str(number)+'.xml'), 'a')
        word_file.write(l)
        page = True
        number += 1

    elif '</page>' in l:
        word_file.write(l)
        word_file.close()
        page = False

    elif page:
        word_file.write(l)


word_file.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Are the new files serialized in a different way and/or different character encoding? That would be the only explanation, really. (Also, might I suggest that instead of splitting the file you consider processing it with a SAX parser?)

Comment: Don't think so. When I run file -bi on wiktionary.xml and on entry.xml both return text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: You're opening the small files with 'a' (append) mode.  If you run this program a second time while the files still exist, the original information gets written again to the file.

Comment: I've checked several of the files. There's no duplication. I'm appending because I'm going line by line (not memory efficient perhaps, but this is a throwaway script). 'w' mode would result in overwriting. I'm running the program once and only once.

Comment: Cat all of the small files together into one big file, which should (theoretically) be identical to the original file.  You might have to alter your script to zero-pad the names, otherwise `10.xml` will come before `2.xml`.  Run a `diff` on the two files.  This will at least tell us where the differences are.

Comment: Also, how did you originally determine that the sizes were different?  Did you run a `wc`?

Comment: Running du -hs on the directory where I'm dumping them. Maybe I'll cat a subset. It's a lot of data.

Comment: du reports **disk block** usage by default, which is not the same thing as file size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93723/discussion-between-zadrozny-and-john-gordon).

Answer (score 1):

Are the smaller files also saved as XML, with the same tag hierarchy?  If so, you're bound to have some tag repetition.

i.e. if you were to split this file:

```
<root>
    <item>abc</item>
    <item>def</item>
    <item>ghi</item>
</root>
```

into three separate files:

```
<root>
    <item>abc</abc>
</root>

<root>
    <item>def</abc>
</root>

<root>
    <item>ghi</abc>
</root>
```

The `<root>` tag is repeated in each smaller file.

It gets worse if your data scheme is more complex:

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <level2>
            <level3>
                <item>abc</item>
            </level3>
        </level2>
    </level1>
</root>
```

Comment: I'm iterating over the file line by line and saving without repetition. Opening the generated files confirms this.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, then.  We can't help unless you show us your code.